# How to enter inside a bracket [] when testing API response body using MockMvc .jsonpath() method

Tags: java, rest, mockmvc

I am new to MockMvc and jsonpath. I did some API testing with rest assured and hamcrest matchers before but I can't figure something out.

How can I get inside the bracket for this response body?

[image]

As you can see the response body contains List of users hence the brackets.. So I don't know what to write inside my expression so I have just written "" but it seems that triggers compiler error.

Any help is appreciated

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I should've used expression as "$.[0]"

This solved my problem.